# Azure DevOps release pipeline is getting failed when executing with publish profile service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using the Azure DevOps release pipeline to deploy a web application built on top of Asp.Net Core to Azure app service. The app service is already up & running.

I created an azure resource manager connection with the publishing profile option through service connections.

[ARM-Publish Profile Service Connection][1]

Later I configured the release pipeline and used Azure app service deploy where I selected the publish profile connection.

[Publish profile connection][2]

As you can see in the screenshot, I was not able to select the already created app service name in the dropdown so I manually entered the app service name and saved the pipeline.

Once the release pipeline got triggered after the CI pipeline, the task failed with exception **credentials can not be null**.

Could someone please help me understand where I am making mistake ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvuGN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLyIl.png

Answer (score 0):

> I was not able to select the already created app service name in the
> dropdown so I manually entered the app service name and saved the
> pipeline, the task failed with exception credentials can not be null.

I can reproduce this problem on my side. I think this is because the azure app service deploy task uses the service principal in the service connection to authenticate with Azure.

As a workaround , we can choose to use the service connection created with the "`Service principal (automatic)`"
option instead of the service connection created with the "`Publish Profile`" option.

[image]

[image]